# What Is Meant by "Maximising" Posterior Probability?

Tags: bayesian, maximum-likelihood, likelihood, posterior, information-theory

My textbook says the following:

> [image]
>
> The optimal coding decision (optimal in the sense of having the smallest probability of being wrong) is to find which value of $\mathbf{s}$ is most probable, given $\mathbf{r}$. Consider the decoding of a single bit $s$, which was encoded as $\mathbf{t}(s)$ and gave rise to three received bits $\mathbf{r} = r_1 r_2 r_3$. By Bayes' theorem, the *posterior probability* of $s$ is
>
> $$P(s | r_1 r_2 r_3) = \dfrac{P(r_1 r_2 r_3 | s) P(s)}{P(r_1 r_2 r_3)}. \tag{1.18}$$
>
> We can spell out the posterior probability of the two alternatives thus:
>
> $$P(s = 1 | r_1 r_2 r_3) = \dfrac{P(r_1 r_2 r_3 | s = 1) P(s = 1)}{P(r_1 r_2 r_3)}; \tag{1.19}$$
>
> $$P(s = 0 | r_1 r_2 r_3) = \dfrac{P(r_1 r_2 r_3 | s = 0) P(s = 0)}{P(r_1 r_2 r_3)}. \tag{1.20}$$
>
> This posterior probability is determine by two factors: the *prior probability* $P(s)$, and the data-dependent term $P(r_1 r_2 r_3 | s)$, which is called the *likelihood* of $s$. The normalising constant $P(r_1 r_2 r_3)$ needn't be computed when finding the optimal decoding decision, which is to guess $\hat{s} = 0$ if $P(s = 0 | \mathbf{r}) > P(s = 1| \mathbf{r})$, and $\hat{s} = 1$ otherwise.
>
> To find $P(s = 0| \mathbf{r})$ and $P(s = 1 | \mathbf{r})$, we must make an assumption about the prior probabilities of the two hypothesis $s = 0$ and $s = 1$, and we must make an assumption about the probability of $\mathbf{r}$ given $s$. We assume that the prior probabilities are equal: $P(s = 0) = P(s = 1) = 0.5$; then maximising the posterior probability $P(s | \mathbf{r})$ is equivalent to maximising the likelihood $P(\mathbf{r} | s)$. And we assume the channel is a binary symmetric channel with noise level $f < 0.5$, so that the likelihood is
>
> $$P(\mathbf{r} \mid s) = P(\mathbf{r} \mid t(s)) = \prod_{n = 1}^N P(r_n \mid t_n(s)), \tag{1.21}$$
>
> where $N = 3$ is the number of transmitted bits in the block we are considering, and
>
> $$P(r_n \mid t_n) = \begin{cases}
>  (1 - f) \qquad & r_n = t_n \\
>  f \qquad &  r_n \not= t_n
> \end{cases} \tag{1.22}$$

*Page 6, Information Theory, Inference, and Learning Algorithms* by David J.C. MacKay

I don't understanding what is meant by "maximising the posterior probability", and therefore, by extension, the following section:

> maximising the posterior probability $P(s | \mathbf{r})$ is equivalent to maximising the likelihood $P(\mathbf{r} | s)$.

What does it mean to "maximise" the posterior probability? And why is it necessary in this context? This makes no sense to me, since when I hear of "maximising" something, I think of calculus. And how is maximising the posterior probability $P(s | \mathbf{r})$ equivalent to maximising the likelihood $P(\mathbf{r} | s)$? It seems to me like these would actually be two different things?

I would greatly appreciate it if people could please take the time to clarify this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Think of $P(s | r)$ as a function of s. Now, without scaling, you compare, say, $P(s = 1 | r) > P(s = 0 | r)$.

**How is maximising the posterior probability P(s|r) equivalent to maximising the likelihood P(r|s)?**

Expand your posterior terms: 
$P(s = i | r) = \frac{P(r | s = i)P(s = i)}{P(r)}$

Then:

$P(s = 1 | r) > P(s = 0 | r) \Rightarrow \\ \quad \frac{P(r | s = 1)P(s = 1)}{P(r)} > \frac{P(r | s = 0)P(s = 0)}{P(r)} \Rightarrow \\ \quad \quad P(r | s = 1)P(s = 1) > P(r | s = 0)P(s = 0) \Rightarrow \\ \quad \quad \quad P(r | s = 1) > P(r | s = 0)$

In line 3, we multiplied both side by $P(r)$ since it is a constant (for both sides ofc). In line 4, we simply divided both sides by 0.5, since $P(s = 0) = P(s = 1) = 0.5$. Hence, your posterior comparison is equal to comparison of likelihoods.

**It seems to me like these would actually be two different things?**

**In case your prior were not uniform, ($P(s = 0) \neq P(s = 1)$), YOU WOULDN'T BE ABLE TO DO THAT, and your posterior maximization would NOT be equal to your likelihood maximization.**

**What does it mean to "maximise" the posterior probability?**

In order to maximize, or find the largest value of posterior ($P(s = i | r)$), you find such an $i$, so that your $P(s = i | r)$ is maximum there. In your case (discrete), you would compute both $P(s = 1 | r)$ and $P(s = 0 | r)$, and find which one is larger, it will be its maximum.

**why is it necessary in this context?**

It is answered in your question:

> The optimal coding decision (optimal in the sense of having the
>   smallest probability of being wrong) is to find which value of s is
>   most probable, given rThe optimal coding decision (optimal in the
>   sense of having the smallest probability of being wrong) is to find
>   which value of s is most probable, given r

PS. If you like calculus, maximizing a discrete probability density is like finding a parameter $i$ in $P(s = i | r)$, which is a value of discrete distribution (which is discrete function) that maximizes its value.